# Settings menu in Ubuntu 17.10 is obliterated

Tags: 17.10, dpkg, settings, gnome-control-center

I have no way of accessing any of my settings on my fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10.  I installed 15 minutes ago, added a few core packages, one of which was wine where `dpkg` failed and I had to restart it.  And it keeps telling me randomly that an install failed of : libsane1 (experimental).

After I installed those packages, no settings available.  The menus are gone, their icons are gone, they won't load even if they have an icon.

As soon as I got the first error message from dpkg, I did a

```
sudo apt-get remove libsane1
```

which went perfectly well and appeared to clear up the error.  Then back and did a

```
sudo apt-get install libsane1
```

which also went perfectly fine and no problems seemed to exist.

Only during the installation of `wine-hq-staging` on my fresh and clean ubuntu does the error appear.  Well it also appears on `winehq-stable` too but I did not use that this occasion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check whether *Settings* (aka `gnome-control-center`) is installed. You may run

```
apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
```

If the output contains `Installed: (none)` install `gnome-control-center` by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Otherwise this package may be corrupted. In that case purge `gnome-control-center` first and reinstall again.